# Can't click on Android widget after app process dies

Tags: android, widget, receiver

I've coded an `Android` widget with two buttons. If i start the "Activity" all works fine and i can click on those buttons. But if i lock the phone, the process dies after a few seconds

> [image]

and i try to click on those buttons again, **nothing** happens, except the `LOGCAT`:

> `I/ActivityManager: filter receiver for action = ButtonRefresh`

`updateAppWidget`, called via `@Override onUpdate(...)`:

```
private final static String BUTTON_REFRESH = "ButtonRefresh";

public static void updateAppWidget(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                   final int appWidgetId) {

    final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.myclasslayout);

    //Click listener depending on @this (getPendingSelfIntent)
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_refresh, getPendingSelfIntent(context, BUTTON_REFRESH));

    [...]

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

`getPendingSelfIntent()`:

```
private static PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

`onReceive()`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (BUTTON_REFRESH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.i("MyLogtag", "Refresh"); //This never shows up in LOGCAT
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
[...]
<receiver android:name=".MyClass">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/myclass_info" />
</receiver>
[...]
```

onReceive **never** gets called when app process is `dead`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it...

i have to change

```
private final static String BUTTON_REFRESH = "ButtonRefresh";
```

to

```
private final static String BUTTON_REFRESH = "com.example.mypackage.BUTTON_REFRESH";
```

and `AndroidManifest`:

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyClass">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="com.example.mypackage.BUTTON_REFRESH"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
    android:resource="@xml/myclass_info" />
</receiver>
```